# Understanding Delete [] c++

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Before all let me say that i have already search for an answer, and i can't find any that explains to me why i'm having problems.

Im a student and im now learning C++

So before tell me to not use C++ in this way, let me say to you that it is for learning purposes and understanding of some comcepts.

Program crashes at very last statement. delete[] tempVector; 
I cant understand why it happens since delete[] vector; works just fine.

The error: play with arr.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Please help me to understand what im doing wrong.

Thank you a lot.

```
class BetterArray
{
private:

    int* vector;
    int count;

public:

    BetterArray(int value);
    BetterArray(int* vec, int size);
    ~BetterArray();

    void add(int value);

    int* getArray();

};

BetterArray::BetterArray(int value)
{
   count = 1;

   vector = new int[1];
   vector[0] = value;   
 }

void BetterArray::add(int value){

    int* tempVector = new int[count + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        tempVector[i] = vector[i];

    tempVector[count] = value;

    count++;

    delete[] vector;

    vector = tempVector;

    delete[] tempVector; // programa crahses here.
}
```

Comment: I don't think the program crashes where you said. However just before the closing } you freed the data you just copied.. `delete[] tempVector;` is the same as saying `delete[] vector;` since both pointers point to the same location.

Comment: What is `vector` in `delete[] vector;`?

Comment: how is `vector` declared?

Comment: Assuming `vector` is a pointer data member like `int* BetterArray::vector`, then assigning `tempVector` to it means they point to the same array. When you delete `tempVector`, you are deleting the array `vector` points to. Now, `vector` points to a deleted array. If the assumption is correct, you can save yourself a ton of trouble by using `std::vector` instead. Assigning a pointer to another does *not* copy the pointed value. It causes the pointers to point to the same instance.

Comment: The solution is to remove this line `delete[] tempVector; // programa crahses here.`

Comment: Your code is incomplete, so any answer can only be speculation. Please include the rest of the class definition that shows what "vector" is and how it is managed.

Answer (score 3):

Crash on `delete` is often a result of a heap corruption. When you assign the `tempVector` pointer to `vector` both pointer point to the same memory location. So deleting `tempVector`  also deletes `vector`. `vector` now points to unassigned memory.

Now assuming you write to `vector`, you are writing to unassigned memory which will corrupt the heap. What happens after this is undefined behaviour but if the heap manager detects the corruption, it will often just crash.